# Which save game does Red Dead Redemption load when starting from the main menu?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

Basically every time when I start up Red Dead Redemption on my XBox, I'm in the following situation: I have a manual save, and additionally an auto-save which is just a few minutes older.

Which one does it load from the start screen?

- Always the auto-save?
- Or always the newest save?

I can never tell the difference, because they're pretty close to each other. So I always have to go into "game -> load game" just to make sure it loads the save game I want.

Comment: Most games load the most recently saved game, so I'd assume that.

Answer (score 1):

The most recently saved game is loaded.

Comment: Make sure your clock is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Like GTA, it loads the most recent save. Try to contact Rockstar Games support.